# Using Carrier Privileges in Android N

Tags: android, telephonymanager, carrier

I want to write an app that uses any function that needs operator privileges to see whether my SIM card and the app are correctly signed.

So I tried to use the following API:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#hasCarrierPrivileges

My problem: 
Although SIM access control files (according to GPAC) are updated by the special rule according to https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/uicc.html 
(ACRF: 30 10 A0 08 04 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF 30 04 04 02 [File ID of ACCF] and ACCF: 30 16 04 14 [SHA-1 of Digital-ID app is signed with] and app is signed with the corresponding certificate matching the hash in the ACCF, I still get hasCarrierPrivileges shown as false.

```
TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
boolean isCarrier=tm.hasCarrierPrivileges();

if (isCarrier) {
   Log.i(TAG, "Ready with carrier privs");
} 
else {
   Log.i(TAG, "No carrier privs");
}
```

I do this in my mainActivity.

Is there anything wrong in my usage? Do I need something special in my manifest?

Comment: I found out that the File ID for AC Rules seems to be hard-coded by Google / Android. So in case of EF_ACRules has different file ID(not 43 00), device cannot access to EF_ACRules.

Comment: So whats the solution you found out. Were you able to get carrier privileges?